# how to highlight current element without overriding styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight an element with a border. The problem is that if we add a wrapper (with border) to an element, it shifts the element a bit.
If we run this script on the page we can see it (with dev tools). Script a little glitchy, because I have troubles to detect when mouse leaves the area.

I can't override parent element properties like (border, outline)
I can't use {position: relative} on the parent element with pseudo-classes::before/after {position: absolute, content: "", border: ....} (because position value can be different on parent element)

For example we select top questions and the button aligns to the text.[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDcjy.png) and
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9JWT.png)

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    var element = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if (element.id === "_wrapper" || element.parentNode.id === "_wrapper" || element.tagName === "HTML" || element.tagName === "BODY") return;
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.id = "_wrapper";
    
    // set the wrapper as child (instead of the element)
    parent.replaceChild(wrapper, element);
    // set element as child of wrapper
    wrapper.appendChild(element);
}, {passive: true})
 
document.addEventListener("mouseout", e => {
    var element = e.target
    if (element.id === "_wrapper") {
        // remove wrapper
        element.replaceWith(...element.childNodes)
        // element.outerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        // element.replaceChild(element.parentNode, element)
        // console.log(element, element.parentNode)
    }
})

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = `
#_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
}
`;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: You could use  `box-shadow` instead of `border`: `div:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px black, inset -1px -1px black;
}`

Comment: it is good until, border-radius (that selected element may have) changes the shape of the rectangle to a circle (

Comment: Temporarily  assign `position: relative`  and a high `z-index` to hovered elements. It can be done with CSS without JavaScript see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76395439/2813224). If it helped upvote, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will include the "border size" inside the element's total size so that it will not make any change to element's previous size.

```
#_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on line 1 of the code, you have a typo: "`mouseove`"

Second:

> ...it shifts the element a bit...

Use `*{box-sizing:border-box}`, to prevent borders from changing an element's width / height.

Here is a snippet, that I use in all my CSS to prevent things like that (you should too, probably):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```